# "stair step" validation chart

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython

I have built a random forest model in ipython/scikit.

```
# Tune Random Forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500,n_jobs=-1)
# fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, sample_weight=sample_weight)

# predict probabilities
model_probs = model.predict_proba(X)
# break out only the event prob
event_probs = model_probs[:,1]
```

I'm able to run cross validated accuracy, precision, recall, F1 scores, and ROC/AUC plots but  what I'd like to do is to create a chart that shows:

"When I predict a probability of 0-10% the event actually happened 5% for that bin. For predicted 10-20% it was 15% ..... For 90-100% it was 92%"

Ideally my model would show a perfect "stair step" showing that as I predict the event is more likely it does in fact occur more often.

I've been able to "bin" the data with:

```
bins = pd.cut(event_probs,bins=10,labels=False)
```

But I just don't know where to go from here.

How do construct that dataframe / plot?

Comment: You could do a scatter plot of your predicted probability with actual probability per bin.

Comment: BrenBarn - Thanks. Sounds worth a try - can you give me a code example? (I'm moving over from R so an example would really help me learn.)

Comment: I guess if I think through this.. Since Y is binary (1 and 0) then the sum of Y / count per bin would be the % of occurrence. Now how to do that?